# How Can Submit Button of HTML Form send email to webmaster without opening user's email client and redirect to another page afterwards?

Tags: php, html, email, forms

I have a very basic HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://someurl.com" target="_new">
    <input name="name" value="" type="text" placeholder="Your First Name"  />
    <input name="from" value="" type="text"  placeholder="Your Best Email" />
    <input type="image" name="image" src="images/submit.gif" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Upon form submit, I'd like for it to redirect to the URL indicated in the form action above AND also for it to send me an email WITHOUT OPENING USER'S MAIL CLIENT notifying of a user filling the form.

For what I gathered online and from this site as well I'd need something like below in php form

```
<?php
///subscribe form
$recipient = "email@email.com"; ///  Your Email address
if (isset($_POST['email']))
  {
  //Send Mail To Webmaster
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $subject = 'New Subscriber';
  $message =  $email . ' has been subscribed to your website.';
  mail("$recipient", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $recipient);
 ;}
 ?>
```

However I'm not proficient enough to create AJAX code to combine the two of them?

I APPRECIATE YOUR HELP, PLEASE BE SPECIFIC! I've seen tons of replies to similar questions with generic answers, if you know I have to use php, ajax etc. please indicate how and provide a sample code. ie. do I need to create a file with that code and how can I call the file and make it work from my HTML form? etc.

UPDATE, ok I found script.js below which is what calls the above php file called mail.php
IT WORKS! however ... it sends the email to myself with the email information of the person that filled the form, not the name.

```
$(function() {
        $(".submit-btn").click(function() {
        var x=$(".mail-input").val();
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        var email = $(".mail-input").val();
        var dataString = 'email='+ email;

        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
        {
        $(".mail-input").css({"background-color":"rgba(216, 70, 55, 0.64)"});
        }
        else
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                window.location.href = "http://someurl.com";
            }
        });
        }
        return false;
        });
```

CAN ANYONE TELL ME how to also capture the name field data of my form and send it in the email as well, looks like the code above is meant for a form with only an email field and sends that data to the webmaster, I need to add the name field from my form to the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ajax for this, just set the form action to your php scripts url.

To redirect the user, you can use the php function [location](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) (demo inside). Just place the call to `location` after the call to `mail`.

Comment: I tried that peaceman, the page is HTML so it wont take the php as action properly. I did find the script.js file for the above code and was able to make it work, however I have an additional issue, I need for the name information from the form to be captured as well and sent in the email to the webmaster

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a few things:

1. I'm not sure if I'm reading the sample php correctly, but do you intend to set the From address to the value in `$_POST['email']`? If so, this is **very** bad practice and will likely result in your web host disabling your ability to send emails from their servers. Make sure that the From address is one that you own or control, not one provided by the user. See my comments and others for a [question where this was the intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819434/some-contact-form-emails-not-being-sent-due-to-spam-filtering-on-host/18819509#18819509).
2. If you want to send the email and then redirect, redirect from the script that handles sending the email instead of setting the redirect URL in the form:

   `<form method="post" action="/form_handler.php" target="_new"></form>`

   ```
   <?php
   ///subscribe form
   $recipient = "email@email.com"; ///  Your Email address
   if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
       //Send Mail To Webmaster
       $email = $_POST['email'] ;
       $subject = 'New Subscriber';
       $message =  $email . ' has been subscribed to your website.';
       mail("$recipient", $subject, $message, "From:" . $recipient);
   }
   header('Location: http://someurl.com/');
   ```
3. In addition to a lot of other issues with the oversimplified script above (it doesn't sanitize the user input, it's very open to a DoS attack, etc), it's not always a good idea to have an externally-dependent event--such as connecting to an email server and sending an email--occur in the actual request/response of the form script. This is something I've learned the hard way. If for some reason the email hangs or the mail server freezes up while sending, etc., the user is left sitting there waiting for the script to move on to the next part (in this case the redirect) and has no idea why the page is not updating (and fyi this is an issue with AJAX as well, it just has slightly different annoying symptoms and can be harder to debug, so don't think that's the easy solution). You may want to consider storing the visitor's email address and other details to a local database or similar and sending the user on their way and then having a scheduler of some kind (usually running via cron on the backend) that periodically checks if there are new email addresses since it last checked and if so sends the emails independent of the user's form submit request.
4. Finally, I would bet a million dollars that there are at least 4 good php frameworks that would handle the security, manage sending the email (and would use SMTP instead of php's limited `mail()` function), would redirect the user and utilizes a scheduler or job queue like I described.  If you're wanting to learn how to handle the scenario you described to improve you skills and understanding of web apps and php, awesome. If you intend to implement the solutions offered here in a real-world site, I strongly recommend stopping now before you get too in over your head (or worse, implement an unsafe, non-secure, unstable solution) and instead look into some of the better lightweight php frameworks.